# A work around for disabled property - Is there more I should be concerned about?

Tags: css, angular, forms, disabled-input

I have a button at the end of a form in Angular.

```
<form>
<!-- form inputs and stuff -->

<!-- hovering on button does not work with disabled -->
<button (mouseover)="findInvalidFieldsAndPutInArray()" [disabled]="myForm.form.invalid" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip that shows Invalid fields: {{ invalidFieldsArray.join(', ')}}">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My current work around is to just bind a CSS class instead of the disabled property in the button so that hovering over via (mouseover) allows the tooltip and function to fire.

```
.cant-click {
  pointer-events: none;
  touch-action: none;
}
```

So my question is, is there more to the **disabled** property that I should know about before removing it in the buttons of my form. Will browsers/screen-readers/crawlers be affected in any negative/misleading way? Or can I just remove it and use the fix listed above?

Comment: `pointer-events: none` is equivalent to setting the button's `disabled` property to true, not sure what you are asking about, it means the button will not react to events at all

Comment: @Dummy: No, it's not. You can still interact with the button using the keyboard. pointer-events, as its name implies, controls whether or not the button responds to *pointer* events only.

Comment: @Dummy Woops.. Thought this property would only disable (click) events.. Yeah your right.. it also disables hover events.. Guess I'll have to add extra HTML to overlay on top of the disabled button to get the (mouseover) event to fire and toggle a message.

Comment: Before was doing an internal API disable method for html elements. Every browser disables in its own way. Pointer-events is not the most best way of disabling on all browsers - for some of them you must apply disable attribute with different values: true or disabled

Comment: @Raphael Do you know the list of properties I should remove from the DOM button to get the desired behavior of allowing hover to fire. (e.g. also prevent touch but allow touch-holding to show tooltip?)